# while program to display even and odd numbers

Tags: loops, while-loop

Ok so my program is supposed to display all even numbers between 50 to 100 on one line separated by 1 comma in between integers and do the same for odd numbers on a separate line. How do I get all my outputs on one line?

***the loop keeps printing***

all even numbers between 50 and 100: 50

all odd numbers between 50 and 100: 51

all even numbers between 50 and 100: 52

all odd numbers between 50 and 100: 53

all even numbers between 50 and 100: 54

all odd numbers between 50 and 100: 55

***it should be***

all even numbers between 50 and 100: 50, 52, 54, 56, etc....

all odd numbers between 50 and 100: 51, 53, 55, 57, etc.....

here's my code

```
 int count = 50;

  while (count <= 100) {

  if (count % 2 == 0){
     System.out.println("Even numbers between 50 and 100: " + count + " ");
     count ++;
     }
  else if (count % 2 == 1){
     System.out.println("\n Odd numbers between 50 and 100: " + count + " ");
     count ++;
     }
  }
  }
  }
```

the entire program has to be under one while loop.

Comment: use System.out.print instead of System.out.println. printlin always prints a line

Comment: Think about how you can keep track of the numbers without necessarily printing them when you find them.

Comment: System.out.print will put everything on one line, mixing the evens and odds.

Comment: I kind of get what you're saying. I moved my print statement out of the while block and it printed out all numbers on a single line so it printed them like 50,51,52,53,54,55,etc...... but now I need to separate them in terms of even and odd.....still not getting it.

Comment: You want your eventual output to be two lines, right? How can you output two different lines after going through one loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

#Program for finding odd&evn number between 2 numbers

echo -n "Enter first number : "
read n1

echo -n "Enter second number : "
read n2

#condition For odd numbers 
if [ $n2 -gt $n1 ];
then
  echo Odd Numbers between $n1 and $n2 are : 
  for(( i=$n1; i<=$n2; i++ ))
  do
    test=$(( $i % 2 ))
    if [ $test -ne 0 ]; 
    then
      echo $i
    fi       
  done

  #condition For even numbers 
  echo Even Numbers between $n1 and $n2 are : 
  for(( i=$n1; i<=$n2; i++ ))
  do
    test=$(( $i % 2 ))
    if [ $test -eq 0 ]; 
    then
      echo $i
    fi       
  done
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$intro2=("These are the even numbers only between 1 and 100: " . "<br><br>");
echo ($intro2); 
$i = 2;
while($i<101) 
{
    echo $i . ", ";
    $i+=2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$intro2=("These are the even numbers only between 1 and 100: " . "<br><br>");
echo ($intro2); 
    $i = 2;
while($i<101) 

{echo $i . ", ";   $i+=2; } 

$break=("<br><br>");
echo ($break);
```

and

```
$intro=("These are the odd numbers only between 1 and 100: " . "<br><br>");
echo ($intro);  
    $i = 1;
while($i<101) 
{echo $i . ", ";   $i+=2; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the Simple Program to Print Even & Odd Numbers from Range 50 - 100 comma separated

```
namespace PurushLogics
{
    class Purush_EvenNo
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int start = 50;
            int end = 100;

            for (int j=start; j <= end; j++)
            {
                if (j % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} ,", j);
                }
            } Console.WriteLine();
            for (int j=start; j <= end; j++)
            {
                if (j % 2 != 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} ," , j);
                }
            }  Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();


        }

    }
}
```